# Showing wait cursor in windows application for log running task

Tags: cursor, wait

I am showing wait cursor with image (System.Drawing.Bitmap) in a windows form and it is not flashing when i click on button and start flashing after event is executed.

As per my understanding wait cursor form did not get focus when event fired and start flashing after event executed

I want to perform this task when user clicks on button event and stop when code end.

I am using vb.net with framework 4.0
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cursor.start()

//ur code

Cursor.stop() !!
simple is that what you wanted??:S if yes mark as answer